# Scala map with implicit conversion

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scala-collections

I have a Scala case class and a corresponding Java class. I've declared an implicit conversion from Scala class to Java class. Now I have a Scala collection of Scala classes, and I want to convert them to Scala collection of Java classes. Is it possible with the implicit conversion? Here's what I've tried, naively perhaps:

```
case class PositionScala(latitude: Double, longitude: Double)
object PositionScala {
  implicit def toJava(p: PositionScala): Position = new Position(p.latitude, p.longitude) // Position is the Java class
}
...
val p: List[Position] = routeScala.shape.map(p => p) 
                     // routeScala.shape is List[PositionScala]
```

But it doesn't compile with the type mismatch error. Of course I can call the conversion function explicitly, but it defeats the purpose of using implicit converter. Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the type annotation in a different place: `routeScala.shape.map(p => p: Position)`. But I'd say this is less clear than just writing `routeScala.shape.map(PositionScala.toJava)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it passing convertion function 'toJava' to map function:

```
val p: List[Position] = routeScala.shape.map(toJava)
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to @alexey-romanov 's answer I should make a stand for scala type resolution.

[`map` method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@map[B](f:A=>B):List[B]) for scala collections have pretty complex behaviour. It tries to derive resulting collection\element type basing on visible `CanBuildFrom` implicit, so it can't say definitely what the result type of `map` argument should be. Because of that it can't apply implicit conversion here.

If for example you had

```
val posOpt: Option[PositionScala] = ???
```

and tried to apply

```
val posJava: Option[Position] = posOpt.map(p => p)
```

It would found your conversion with no problem.

Comment: `map` method link link is broken.

Comment: @Haspemulator ty, fixed